# Dynamically creating AJAX CascadingDropDown

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, cascadingdropdown

I have to dynamically add many AJAX CascadingDropDown control sets (with different data). The data is to be read from a database. Can [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32725/Using-CascadingDropDown-with-a-Database) approach be use for dynamic creation? Would it be better to have a Web User Control that can be added dynamically. I don't get a clear picture of how to implement this. Any suggestions/hints on the best way to go about would be very helpful.

```
Item 1: Company | Product | Model
Item 2: Company | Product | Model
..
Item n: Company | Product | Model
```

Comment: You can do it programtically using Custom UserControls, where you will have to be careful is recreating the controls on every postback and ensure the ViewState does not become corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start checking this toolkit:
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

Comment: Already checked it. But my concern is whether it would work when I need to dynamically create these controls.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to dynamically load in the sense that you don't know the control until runtime, you can make a asp:placeholder and then call a function that creates the control as desired , then use placeholdername.Controls.Add(newdropdown). You can do this via Ajax though I would also recommend the Telerik library as their Ajax Control makes this click and point easy.